# Error uploading R Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have tried uploading the R Shiny app I created online but it keeps on saying
'Object Nutrition not found'. My files are located all together in a folder and I just pressed the publish button from the R console.

My ui.R code:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Nutrition Data App"),
  p(em("This Dataset contains nutrition data on fastfood places")),
  p(strong("This app allows users to browsefood items and places and see         nutritional value!")),

 sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("Location","Location",
              choice = c(levels(Nutrition$Location)),
              selected = "KFC")

),

mainPanel(
  plotOutput("barplot"),
  br(),br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)
)
))
```

My server.R code:

```
Nutrition <- read.csv("NutritionData.csv", header=T, na.strings=c("","NA"))
Nutrition = Nutrition[,1:10]
Nutrition$Location = as.factor(Nutrition$Location)

library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 filtered = reactive({
 Nutrition %>% 
  filter(Location == input$Location
  )
 })


output$barplot = renderPlot({
Calories = filtered()[,4]
hist(Calories,xlim = c(0,1000),ylim = c(0,30),col = c("blue"))
})

output$text = renderPrint({
cat("The mean calories of the selected group is", mean(filtered()$Calories))
})


})
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno.. this code worked fine for me:

```
    ui = fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Nutrition Data App"),
  p(em("This Dataset contains nutrition data on fastfood places")),
  p(strong("This app allows users to browsefood items and places and see         nutritional value!")),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Location","Location",
                  choice = c(levels(Nutrition$Location)),
                  selected = "KFC")

    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("barplot"),
      br(),br(),
      verbatimTextOutput("text")
    )
  )
)


Nutrition <- read.csv("e://NutritionData.csv", header=T, na.strings=c("","NA"))
Nutrition = Nutrition[,1:10]
Nutrition$Location = as.factor(Nutrition$Location)

library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

server =shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  filtered = reactive({
    Nutrition %>% 
      filter(Location == input$Location
      )
  })


  output$barplot = renderPlot({
    Calories = filtered()[,4]
    hist(Calories,xlim = c(0,1000),ylim = c(0,30),col = c("blue"))
  })

  output$text = renderPrint({
    cat("The mean calories of the selected group is", mean(filtered()$Calories))
  })


})



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```